# Wordpress - Allow older and newer post buttons navigate to a ID

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am looking for a way to modify the below PHP to allow the addition of a ID that once pressed will navigate the user to the start of the blog posts instead of the top of the page.

```
<div class="post-navigation">
    <?php next_posts_link( 'Older Posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Posts' ); ?>
</div>
```

I feel like this is somethign that should be possible without a plugin although I have found a plugin that would allow me to do this piece of functionality.

The intended story would go something like this:

1. User clicks on 'older' or 'newer' button that would have in the url something like domainName.co.uk/page/2#startofposts
2. The user then would have the browser refresh and instead of the page being loaded at the top it would be loaded where the ID 'startofposts' would be in the DOM.

Anyone done this without a plugin?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var startID = '#post-container';
  var urlString = window.location;
  var caseSearch = '/page/'
  if(urlString.indexOf(caseSearch) != -1 {
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery(startID).offset().top);
  }
}
```

this should do the trick. There are better ways to do this but for a quick solution id should be fine.

Comment: Hmm not a bad idea. Without knowing how to add a hash with the newer and older posts buttons on click we wouldn't be able to do the if statement though.

Comment: if you have the start of your posts wrapped in a container, you could then onload take them to that class or ID of the container. If you like this idea i can provide you with the script for it?

Comment: ah I see so you create the hash when they click on it instead of after. I get ya. If you don't mind that would be great

Comment: well there is no need to create a hash. You will use the page/2 and the just scroll them to the div where the posts start. Provide me with the class that wraps the start of your posts.

Comment: Ah ok, I''m using the ID post-container at the moment.

Comment: Sorry my message didn't send.. I'm using the ID post-container.

Comment: added the script, hope it helps

Comment: I get this error im afraid. Uncaught TypeError: urlString.indexOf is not a function

Answer (score 0):

In the end I appended the wanted ID onto the end of the anchors manually.. preventing me from having to do anything too fancy.

```
$('.post-navigation a').each(function () {
    var current = $(this);
    var href = current.attr("href");
    current.attr("href", href + '#post-container');
});
```